# Github Pages not displaying CSS and image fil

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I have uploaded all of my files to my repo. Everything seems to be working fine locally but the CSS files and images are not loading on the actual website.

Link to the repo: https://github.com/Hammad-H/Hammad-H.github.io

Comment: https://hammad-h.github.io/ looks good to me.

Comment: You are required to post a complete but minimal example of your problem markup or code **here within your question**, not a third party site, that allows us to duplicate the issue: [mcve]

Comment: As soon as your site's code is updated, your question becomes useless to future readers.  That's why we ask the code be *part of the question*.

Answer (score 0):

have you linked them correctly using:

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssFileName.css">
```